# How to standardize non-numeric characters in a column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I need to give the same name (values) to a non-numeric characters in a column composed by universities. An example of my table listed below. Of course, there is many other names of universities, people and columns. I just need to change this part of the data frame.

| Name | Affiliation |
| --- | --- |
| Jose Ramayana | OXFORD UNIVERSITY |
| Andres Andresius | OFORD UNIVERSITY |
| Pepito Perez | UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL |
| Cacolo Osorio | Universidad Nacional de Bogotá |
| Maleja Patras | Unievrsidad del Valle |
| Tigre Tony | Universidad Nacional |
| Pocho Valencia | UNIVERSIDAD DEL VALLE |
| Puti Gutierrez | OXFORD UNIVERSITY |
| Chuchi Lopez | UPTC |
| Ganso Salazar | Uptc |
| Santiago Andrade | PONTIFICIA UNIVERSIDAD JAVERIANA |
| Andrés Tigreros | JAVERIANA CALI |

I was trying to use this code but I justo got many replications of the same person at least 10 times.

```
DB_CO1<- DB_CO %>%
        mutate(FinalAssociation = map(affiliation, ~DB_CO$affiliation[str_detect(.x,DB_CO$affiliation)])) %>% 
          unnest (cols = c(FinalAssociation))
```

Desired result: that all the values in affiliation stay as the same of some way

| Name | Affiliation |
| --- | --- |
| Jose Ramayana | OXFORD UNIVERSITY |
| Andres Andresius | OXFORD UNIVERSITY |
| Pepito Perez | UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL DE BOGOTÁ |
| Cacolo Osorio | UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL DE BOGOTÁ |
| Maleja Patras | UNIVERSIDAD DEL VALLE |
| Tigre Tony | UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL DE BOGOTÁ |
| Pocho Valencia | UNIVERSIDAD DEL VALLE |
| Puti Gutierrez | OXFORD UNIVERSITY |
| Chuchi Lopez | UPTC |
| Ganso Salazar | UPTC |
| Santiago Andrade | PONTIFICIA UNIVERSIDAD JAVERIANA CALI |
| Andrés Tigreros | PONTIFICIA UNIVERSIDAD JAVERIANA CALI |

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show what your desired output is?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be doing any replacement, just detecting whether some string is found. As far as I can tell, you're just marking off whether the affiliation column contains the affiliation column...that's not going to prove very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `agrep` solution relies on several assumptions.

1. A fuzzy match between the items is possible (i.e. no heavily abbreviated names like *UN* etc)
2. The longer string is the desired name.
3. No ambiguities occurs.

```
dat_n <- sapply( dat$Affiliation, function(x)
  dat$Affiliation[agrep(x,dat$Affiliation,ignore.case = TRUE)] )

dat$Affiliation_new <- toupper( unlist(sapply( dat_n, function(x)
  x[which.max( nchar(x) )] )) )

               Name                      Affiliation
1     Jose Ramayana                OXFORD UNIVERSITY
2  Andres Andresius                 OFORD UNIVERSITY
3      Pepito Perez             UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL
4     Cacolo Osorio   Universidad Nacional de Bogotá
5     Maleja Patras            Unievrsidad del Valle
6        Tigre Tony             Universidad Nacional
7    Pocho Valencia            UNIVERSIDAD DEL VALLE
8    Puti Gutierrez                OXFORD UNIVERSITY
9      Chuchi Lopez                             UPTC
10    Ganso Salazar                             Uptc
11 Santiago Andrade PONTIFICIA UNIVERSIDAD JAVERIANA
12  Andrés Tigreros                   JAVERIANA CALI
                    Affiliation_new
1                 OXFORD UNIVERSITY
2                 OXFORD UNIVERSITY
3    UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL DE BOGOTÁ
4    UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL DE BOGOTÁ
5             UNIEVRSIDAD DEL VALLE
6    UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL DE BOGOTÁ
7             UNIEVRSIDAD DEL VALLE
8                 OXFORD UNIVERSITY
9                              UPTC
10                             UPTC
11 PONTIFICIA UNIVERSIDAD JAVERIANA
12                   JAVERIANA CALI
```

**Data**

```
dat <- structure(list(Name = c("Jose Ramayana", "Andres Andresius",
"Pepito Perez", "Cacolo Osorio", "Maleja Patras", "Tigre Tony",
"Pocho Valencia", "Puti Gutierrez", "Chuchi Lopez", "Ganso Salazar",
"Santiago Andrade", "Andrés Tigreros"), Affiliation = c("OXFORD UNIVERSITY",
"OFORD UNIVERSITY", "UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL", "Universidad Nacional de Bogotá",
"Unievrsidad del Valle", "Universidad Nacional", "UNIVERSIDAD DEL VALLE",
"OXFORD UNIVERSITY", "UPTC", "Uptc", "PONTIFICIA UNIVERSIDAD JAVERIANA",
"JAVERIANA CALI")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering mate! But I don't know if I'm just doing something wrong while using this code. I'm getting just a new list of all the universities as many sets by row. I already complete my question if may help in something.

Comment: @AndrésFelipeTigreros-Andrade I put in the changes. As you can see it almost gets everything right. Just `JAVERIANA CALI` is not recognized. It's because the difference it too large. If you change it to just `JAVERIANA` it works. This is probably the best you can get without a template set to choose from. Its kind of unsupervised replacement, which is always tricky.

Comment: @AndrésFelipeTigreros-Andrade Btw, I put the replacements into ..._new to show the changes next to the old values. Simply use `dat$Affiliation <- toupper( unlist(sapply( dat_n, function(x)
  x[which.max( nchar(x) )] )) )` as the second line to replace the old values.

Comment: @AndrésFelipeTigreros-Andrade Oh, and choosing the correct between `UNIVERSIDAD DEL VALLE` and `UNIEVRSIDAD DEL VALLE` is impossible without a template.